# Struggling with Regex for adjacent letters differing by case

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to be able to recursively remove adjacent letters in a string that differ only in their case e.g. if s = AaBbccDd i would want to be able to remove Aa Bb Dd but leave cc.

I can do this recursively using lists:

I think it aught to be able to be done using regex but i am struggling:

with test string 'fffAaaABbe' the answer should be 'fffe' but the regex I am using gives 'fe'

```
def test(line):
    res = re.compile(r'(.)\1{1}', re.IGNORECASE)
    #print(res.search(line))
    while res.search(line):
        line = res.sub('', line, 1)
    print(line)
```

The way that works is:

```
def test(line):
    result =''
    chr = list(line)
    cnt = 0
    i = len(chr) - 1

    while i > 0:
        if ord(chr[i]) == ord(chr[i - 1]) + 32 or ord(chr[i]) == ord(chr[i - 1]) - 32:
            cnt += 1
            chr.pop(i)
            chr.pop(i - 1)
            i -= 2
        else:
            i -= 1
    if cnt > 0: # until we can't find any duplicates.
        return test(''.join(chr))
    result = ''.join(chr)
    print(result)
```

Is it possible to do this using a regex?

Comment: What is the output for AaA?

Comment: Run on AaA outputs A

Answer (score 1):

`re.IGNORECASE` is not way to solve this problem, as it will treat `aa`, `Aa`, `aA`, `AA` same way. Technically it is possible using `re.sub`, following way.

```
import re
txt = 'fffAaaABbe'
after_sub = re.sub(r'Aa|aA|Bb|bB|Cc|cC|Dd|dD|Ee|eE|Ff|fF|Gg|gG|Hh|hH|Ii|iI|Jj|jJ|Kk|kK|Ll|lL|Mm|mM|Nn|nN|Oo|oO|Pp|pP|Qq|qQ|Rr|rR|Ss|sS|Tt|tT|Uu|uU|Vv|vV|Ww|wW|Xx|xX|Yy|yY|Zz|zZ', '', txt)
print(after_sub)  # fffe
```

Note that I explicitly defined all possible letters pairs, because so far I know there is no way to say "inverted case letter" using just `re` pattern. Maybe other user will be able to provide more concise `re`-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach which uses `groupby` to group adjacent similar letters:

```
from itertools import groupby

def test(line):
    res = []
    for k, g in groupby(line, key=lambda x: x.lower()):
        g = list(g)
        if all(x == x.lower() for x in g):
            res.append(''.join(g))             
    print(''.join(res))
```

**Sample run**:

```
>>> test('AaBbccDd')
cc
>>> test('fffAaaABbe')
fffe
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this fails for test('AaA') should return A but returns nothing. Also test('AaAb') should return 'Ab' only returns b.

Comment: *"..remove adjacent letters in a string that differ only in their case"*. Does not that mean `'AaA'` return an empty string and `'AaAb'` return just `'b'` ?

Comment: My bad. I should have said pairs of adjacent  and I did elude to that in the answered comment to the question. Someone asked what the result was for 'AaA' and to be fair the posted working code in my question quite clearly works in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

`r'(.)\1{1}'` is wrong because it will match any character that is repeated twice, including non-letter characters. If you want to stick to letters, you can't use this.

However, even if we just do `r'[A-z]\1{1}'`, this would still be bad because you would match any sequence of the same letter twice, but it would catch `xx` and `XX` -- you don't want to match consecutive same characters with matching case, as you said in the original question.

It just so happens that there is no short-hand to do this conveniently, but it is still possible. You could also just write a small function to turn it into a short-hand.

Building on @Daweo's answer, you can generate the regex pattern needed to match pairs of same letters with non-matching case to get the final pattern of `aA|Aa|bB|Bb|cC|Cc|dD|Dd|eE|Ee|fF|Ff|gG|Gg|hH|Hh|iI|Ii|jJ|Jj|kK|Kk|lL|Ll|mM|Mm|nN|Nn|oO|Oo|pP|Pp|qQ|Qq|rR|Rr|sS|Ss|tT|Tt|uU|Uu|vV|Vv|wW|Ww|xX|Xx|yY|Yy|zZ|Zz`:

```py
import re
import string

def consecutiveLettersNonMatchingCase():
  # Get all 'xX|Xx' with a list comprehension
  # and join them with '|'
  return '|'.join(['{0}{1}|{1}{0}'.format(s, t)\
    # Iterate through the upper/lowercase characters
    # in lock-step
    for s, t in zip(
      string.ascii_lowercase,
      string.ascii_uppercase)])

def test(line):
    res = re.compile(consecutiveLettersNonMatchingCase())
    print(res.search(line))
    while res.search(line):
        line = res.sub('', line, 1)
    print(line)

print(consecutiveLettersNonMatchingCase())
```